# Fixed effects regression with a large number of individuals

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Does it make sense to use a fixed effect regression to estimate individual effects when the number of individuals is very large (i.e. multiple thousands of $\alpha_i$)?
If not, are there any solid alternative methodologies to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Computational time?

Comment: Computational time may be an issue, but my question was more of a high level one: I am working on a sample that would require more than 400k individual effects (I am interested in the individual effects for 2k individuals over a 20 year period on a monthly basis) to be estimated and I was wondering whether there are any alternative methodologies, simply because a fixed effects regression with 400k dummies seems a bit too messy.

Comment: Can you group them into clusters and reduce the dimensionality?

Comment: No, I can't, as it would defeat the purpose of the analysis.

Comment: Then I can't see a way around it.